# programmatically execute Touch event in android

Tags: android

Can we execute touch event programmatically in android by some method, such as passing screen co-ordinates(x,y)? Is there any such method? Please guide me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if it works, but try this:

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, 
                                       x, y, pressure, size, 
                                       metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, 
                                       deviceId, edgeFlags);
onTouchEvent(event);
```

Comment: can u little bit explain it....how can i get these value i.e downtime,eventtime etc.

Comment: i want to click button programmatically using this code but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could call

```
View.onTouchEvent (MotionEvent)
```

when you know the destination

When you want to address some child or grand-child,

```
View.dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent)
```

is better

However, you have to supply an self crafted motion event.
The MotionEvent holds the coordinates, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using **dispatchTouchEvent** and give it **MotionEvent** instance like below

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, pressure, size, metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, deviceId, edgeFlags))
```

you can find more help in this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Answer (score -3):

There is a special method for this:

```
View.performClick()
```

Comment: This calls the views OnClickListener, not OnTouchListener