# How to show mouse cursor on screen of an android tablet?

Tags: java, android, tcp, mouse, android-cursor

I would like to be able to show on the tablet screen something like the mouse cursor.I am sending the cursor position using `TCP PACKET`.How to make a cursor that move in my android screen according to position that is send using TCP Packet.My linux laptop is sending the coordinate to my tablet.And the cursor in tablet should move accordingaly.Any help toward this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit your questions to change them.

Comment: This question is related to my previous question....

Comment: Again: Do not change your existing question, if you have a new question. Press the button on top/right of the screen labeled "Ask Question" to create  new question.

Comment: ok man...but both of the question were almost similar :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [system overlay window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY) for this, a starting point might be [this short article](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/android-overlay-cursor/#.U2d_wLbwCUk).

Comment: thanx man @udo ....problem has been solved.Now mouse is working in my laptop .is their any option by which i can implement mouse click in android

Comment: You're welcome. Better ask a new question, you will have a bigger audience ...

Comment: thanx man @udo it was great help from ur side...if u know something about mouse click.plz share ur view..

Comment: Srb, this is not how StackOverflow works. Create a new question, leave the old as it is, especially after you have already accepted it. With a new question, other people will have a look at it and you will get much more audience. People who answer do not look at old questions. Please undo your changes in the question subject and text, leave this answer as accepted for futur search reference and create a brand new question with a new topic.

Comment: Thanks. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787699/programmatically-execute-touch-event-in-android

Comment: thnx man...i m working on this..