# Click on pixel Android

Tags: android

I want to click on place of the screen (I have width and height).

Suppose we have mobile phone with resolution 1280x720 and we want to click on 560x431. Maybe with `TouchUtils` but how?

Comment: Maybe you can put a simple transparent button in that position and set the onClickListener;)

Comment: Do you want to tap the screen on the exact coordinate with your fingers or programatically? If former, I can only wish you good luck. If latter, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787888/905349).

Comment: Hmm... suppose that we have mouse cursor on the screen. We only know x and y where's the cursor. When we have mouse on the button we can click and press the button