# Android second view doesn't receive focus while first view is in touch

Tags: android, view, focus, ontouchlistener

I have two ImageViews one is full screen and in background (iv1), the other one is wrapping its contents and in foreground(iv2).

Every Imageview has it own `OnTouchListener`.

When user clicks on iv1 and drags over iv2, iv2 doesn't receive touches, and I need that behaviour, I tried

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
```

on iv2 but with no luck. can you guys help me?

Comment: you may be able to programmatically release the when second view getting focus and create touch event again to second view. this link [to create touch event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787699/programmatically-execute-touch-event-in-android) and this for [release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902892/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-touch-event-in-android)

Comment: how? the second view onTouch is not getting called